# Touch events work on document element but not on a div container

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my code using the div container:

```
<html><body>
<div id="container">Test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">   
  var xDown=null;
  var yDown=null;
  function handleTouchStart(e){
     xDown=e.touches[0].clientX;
     yDown=e.touches[0].clientY;
  }
  function handleTouchMove(e){
     alert('Swiped');
  }
  //Tried this:
  document.getElementById("container").ontouchstart=function(e){
    handleTouchStart(e);
  };
  document.getElementById("container").ontouchmove=function(e){
    handleTouchMove(e);
  };
  // and tried this
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('touchstart',handleTouchStart,false);
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('touchmove',handleTouchMove,false);
</script>
</body></html>
```

**Now since theres only one html div i would imagine this div should take up the entire page for swiping. This is not the effect. It only seems to work on the upper left corner.**

Now when I `drop the div` and use the document instead it works perfect:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart',handleTouchStart,false);
document.addEventListener('touchmove',handleTouchMove,false);
```

How do I get the touch gestures to work on my div? **The goal is to eventually move the code to a modal window that can scroll photos left and right**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It works fine.

What's wrong here is this assumption you've made:

> Now since theres only one html div i would imagine this div should
>   take up the entire page for swiping.

You need to make the `div` fill the entire page. Use this css class.

```
.full-screen {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Apply this class to the `html` and `document` element, as well as your `div`

```
<html class="full-screen">
<body class="full-screen">
    <div id="container" class="full-screen">Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```